# How do I point the one array element to the other array element in a different array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am taking a input from a file as a string and storing values in a struct.

Example Input: "`R1 10`"

I have stored the string R1 in ,say, `operation_string[i].rsrc1`
and 10 in, say, `operation_string[i].literal`

Now, I want to simply use R1 as a block to store value 10 inside it, which I guess could be done through arrays and pointers.

But I'm not sure how.

Comment: *...I want to simply use R1 as a block to store value 10 inside it...* I didn't get this, can you explain a little more, perhaps with an example

Comment: I'm actually making a simulator and R1 is my register and 10 is my literal, so if I get an input string "R1 10", it means that I should store the value 10 in R1.

Comment: Thats really some crucial information you missed in your question. Anyways, how do you access this register?

Comment: @Haris, I'm just accessing an input string from a text file which reads like "R1 10", now, I am thinking to create an array which points the string R0, R1, R2.., and stores value in it.
Like: R1 points to arr[1] and stores 10 in it.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Maybe you have special requirements, but why not just make each register an element in an array, and then put the value in the corresponding register? For  example, `R[1] = 10;`, where R is your array of registers R[1] is simply R1 and you just stored 10 in it.